# Why would Redis allow client to shutdown server?

Tags: redis

I installed redis on my computer and opened 1 redis-server and 2 redis-cli. If I type "shutdown save" command in the first redis-cli terminal, it will close both the server and the first redis-cli. Then, the second redis-cli won't be able to communicate with redis-server anymore because it has already been shutdown by the other redis-cli. **It just doesn't make sense to me**. IMO, a server is a standalone service and should always be running. A client should be able to connect/disconnect with a server but never disable a server. Why would Redis allow a client to disable a server which could be shared by many other clients? Consider if the redis server is on a remote machine and the redis clients are on other machines, wouldn't it be very dangerous since if one of the clients shut down the remote server then all other clients will be influenced?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want clients to execute the `SHUTDOWN` command (or any other for that matter), you can use the `rename-command` configuration directive.

As of the upcoming Redis v6, ACL are expected to provide a better degree of control over admin and application command.

Answer (score 0):

No, I think you are getting it wrong. It's application responsibility to allow/disallow certain specific action on remote server. You can simply disallow certain commands so that single cli cannot take down the redis-server.